# Fail to retrieve JSON entity from Google Datastore using BigQuery

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to export an entity from Google Data Store to Big Query (and then to CSV).

When I create the dataset, everything turns fine except for one missing variable that is supposed to be a JSON.(`ndb.JsonProperty()`)

Looking at this entity variable in the datastore, it seems to be an encoded JSON (eg : ...`0NzIyMDUyODkiLCAidXNlcl9uYW1lIjogIlZpbmNlbnQgR`...)

My only purpose is to export this entity from the datastore using Big Query, Python or whatever needed, in order to explore the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ndb JsonProperty values are stored in the datastore as [blobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types):

> **JsonProperty**  Value is a Python object (such as a list or a dict or a string) that is serializable using Python's json module; Cloud Datastore stores the JSON serialization as a blob.

BigQuery [discards blob data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore#data_type_conversion):

> **Blob**  BigQuery discards these values when loading the data.

One possible workaround is to create [Computed Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#computed) on your model to extract the data that you're interested in in a format that BigQuery will accept.

For example, say you are storing a `dict` like this in your `JsonProperty`:

```
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'quux'}
```

Let's say you are interested in the value corresponding to the key `foo`.  You can create a `ComputedProperty` that returns the value, and this will be picked up by your BigQuery export (note you must save all your model instances after a `ComputedProperty` has been added to populate the new property).

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):

   blob = ndb.JsonProperty()
   foo = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.blob.get('bar'))

obj = MyModel(blob=data)
obj.put()
obj.foo
'bar'
```

Comment: That clarifies, thanks. I'm not sure to understand your last example though : to what `'bar'` make reference to ? Is `self.blob` a reference to the `blob` you define above or to the blob type ? Finally, is this meant to convert my existing blob variable to a readable one or will this apply only to the futurely created ones ?